# ExpressionEngine 1.67 - Upgraded PHP, tags not loading

Tags: php, tags, expressionengine

We’re using EE1.67 and recently upgraded PHP so had the ereg issues (which I solved by replacing it with preg_match) and I had some pass by reference issues so I replaced all the &$ with just $ - but now my tags are showing like {photo} instead of the actual dynamic content.

I don’t know the original developer that did the site so I can not find an upgrade link to get to 1.73 so I need a code fix for this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this mirror of [the change log](http://www.sundance.org/temp/eedoc/changelog.html).

Note especially:

1.6.8 brings compatibility with PHP 5.3

and 1.6.8 included a major security fix.

Note also that there we other security fixed between 1.6.7 and 1.7.3.

I would strongly recommend that you contact ellis lab and try to get access to the updater.  Fixing a couple of PHP functions to work around error is not enough IMO.

Even without the details from the original site developer you should be able to quote to Ellislabs the license number from the "General Configuration" pane of the control panel.

Comment: I eventually did an upgrade to 1.73 and also upped the version of the FieldFrame (the issue with the tags) to 1.35. Now my links are broken due to the Structure Module. First I lost everything in the exp_sites.site_pages column which I restored from an old backup and the URLs are there now, but going to them cases a 404.

Comment: But that was also on a server that was back at php 5.3 instead of 5.4